# Pass value of a field to another content type in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type 'Exhibit' with fields 'uuid'(text with single value), 'name'(text with single value), 'description'(long text and summary), 'section'(text with unlimited values). I have used views to display 'Exhibit' in table format.
[image: Exhibit view]

Now when i click on Add section. I want the field Section in Exhibit view to be uuid values in Section content type. I want the uuid values as a drop down . so that customer can select one uuid and enter the details for that uuid. How can i achieve this? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would make sense if your 'exhibit' content type references sections, which are themselves nodes (through nid reference fields) or through a reference field on the section that points back to the exhibit.  Then you can build the view with relationships to look however you want.

The point of having everything be a node is that you can take advantage of a lot of built-in functionality, as well as a lot of contrib modules which are **geared towards nodes**.

So if you create the structure as I mentioned above, you can add sections to exhibits with this module: [Node Reference URL](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url), which allows you to automatically fill in the nid reference field.

Does that work?

Comment: will try this and let you know if it worked

Comment: I tried this. but what I am getting is the title of the 'Exhibit' content type as 'uuid' values for section. But I want the 'section' field values of 'Exhibit' content type as 'uuid' values for 'Section' content type.

Comment: Does it matter which content type is referencing which?  Views will let you display them properly, with the correct relationships setup, with either scenario, right?  Is that (the view) the part that's causing you issues?

Comment: I think I haven't made my question clear. It matters which content type it is referencing. Because depending on the selected 'uuid' values of section content type , customer needs to fill the remaining fields for that particular uuid value. After that views can be used to display those particular values.